# How to test Devise Sessions Controller with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I override SessionsController in my own controller and tried to test with RSpec. Fist, I setup devise with

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

require 'authentication_helper'

RSpec.describe Users::SessionsController, type: :controller do
  include AuthenticationHelper

describe 'create new session' do

```
before(:each) do
  setup_auth
end

let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user, username: 'john', email: 'john@gmail.com', password: 'pwd1234')}

it 'should return 200 with valid username and password' do
  post :create, user: {login: 'john', password: 'pwd1234'}

  expect(response).to have_http_status 200
  expect(controller.current_user.id).to eq(user.id)
end
```

end
end

my SessionsController just return http 401 or http 200.
When I run my spec, I get this error:

NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:103:in`require_no_authentication'
     # ./spec/controllers/users/sessions_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:45:in`block (3 levels) in '
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.0/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:16:in `cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:98:in`cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in`call'
     # /usr/local/bundle/gems/database_cleaner-1.6.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:44:in`block (2 levels) in '

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You know that Devise offers RSpec test helpers for controller specs. However, in request specs, they will not work.

Here is a solution for request specs, adapted from the Devise wiki. We will simply use Warden's test helpers – you probably already load them for your Cucumber tests.

First, we define sign_in and sign_out methods. These will behave just like those you know from controller specs:

```
module DeviseRequestSpecHelpers

include Warden::Test::Helpers

def sign_in(resource_or_scope, resource = nil)
  resource ||= resource_or_scope
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  login_as(resource, scope: scope)
end

def sign_out(resource_or_scope)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  logout(scope)
end
end
```

Finally, load that module for request specs:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include DeviseRequestSpecHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Done. You can now write request specs like this:

```
sign_in create(:user, name: 'John Doe')
visit root_path
expect(page).to include('John Doe')
```

**Reference:**
https://makandracards.com/makandra/37161-rspec-devise-how-to-sign-in-users-in-request-specs

Comment: You answered a question, but not this one. Question is "how do I test my custom Sessions controller?" not "how do I bypass Devise authentication in my specs?".

Answer (score 1):

You have to stub out the `warden.authenticate!` call, not just the `current_user` method.

For login success test cases:

```
before(:each) do
  # assuming `user` is defined and returns a User instance
  allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
  allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
end
```

For failure cases:

```
before(:each) do
  allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, scope: :user)
  allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
end
```

This works for me in devise 4.x. Found this in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

Answer (score -1):

You should have a helper for the sign in, for example

```
module AuthenticationHelpers
     module Controller
        def sign_in(user)
           controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(user)
           controller.stub(:user_id).and_return(user.id)
        end
    end

  module Feature
      def sign_in(user, options={})
          visit "/users/sign_in"
          fill_in "Email", with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: options[:password]
          click_button "Log in"
      end
  end
end
```

Any concerns, do not hesitate to comment

Comment: There is no way to test just my sessions controller? I'm performing login by Ajax, that's why I just want to test if my controller is returning 200 and 401 correctly.

Comment: As I see that in the Spec file they are requiring _require 'authentication_helper'_ , so I think I should have the file

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.